# How to use slot ADesignFullCalendar Bundle Symfomy2

Tags: javascript, symfony, fullcalendar

I install and use [ADesigns Bundle](https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle). 
Tried allDaySlot, slotMinutes, slotDuration but doesn't work.  How can I enable to Hours Slots.

Comment: Please, add some relevant code because we cannot guess nothing from this "one-line" question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I soleved. Just add `defaultView: 'agendaWeek',`